# No sé como llenar un vector de una posición en una

Tags: array, c

No se como puedo hacer que un vector de tamaño N, se pueda llenar de una posición en otra, es decir primero llenar la posición [0], con un dato ingresado por el usuario a través de la consola, luego de hacer esto que se muestre un mensaje para ver si el usuario desea llenar la siguiente posición del vector (posición[1]), y que las otras posiciones mientras no se llenen queden en 0.

```
    int ingresarMoneda()
    {
    int monedas=0;
    //capacidad es una variable global, puede tomar cualquier valor mayor a uno
    //vecDenominaciones[n] es un vector en el cual ingreso valores que son validos, me ayuda a validar a denominación ingresada, n puede ser cualquier valor entre 1 y 6.
    //vecCantidadMonedas[capacidad], es el vector que deseo llenar posición por posición
    int denominacionIngresada;
    leerEntero(&denominacionIngresada);
        for(int i=0;i<cantidadDenominaciones;i++){

                if(denominacionIngresada==vecDenominaciones[i]){
                    monedas=1;
                    imprimir("nice");

                }   VecCantidadMonedas[i]=denominacionIngresada;
        }if(monedas==0){
            do{
                imprimir("de nuevo.");
                leerEntero(&denominacionIngresada);
                for(int i=0;i<cantidadDenominaciones;i++){

                    if(denominacionIngresada==vecDenominaciones[i]){
                        monedas=1;
                        imprimir("nice");
                    }   VecCantidadMonedas[i]=denominacionIngresada;
                }
            }while(monedas==0);


}return 0;
}
```

Esa función me valida un numero, y quiero que ese numero validado llene la posición [0], del vector vecCantidad[capacidad]; y luego preguntar si se desea repetir la operación ingresar nuevamente un valor y una vez validado llenar la posición[1] del vecCantidad[capacidad];

Comment: Lo que quieres es pedirle al usuario que ingrese un dato y después decirle si desea seguir ingresando datos. El vector por defecto tendrá almacenado puros ceros. ¿Eso es lo que quieres hacer?

Answer (score -1):

puedes utilizar un bucle de validacion do..while y cuando el usuario decida ingresar otro numero incrementa a una unidad adicional de la variable que controla la posicion del vector. para que tu siguiente ciclo pase de vecCantidad[0] a vecCantidad[1]